# MySQL separate users for read, write, and admin

Tags: mysql, sql

I took a MySQL class a couple years ago where the instructor had us create separate users with different permissions on the tables as a last line of defense against attacks like SQL injection. The users would basically be created like this:

```
CREATE USER 'read'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT ON * TO 'read'@'localhost';

CREATE USER 'write'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON * TO 'write'@'localhost';

CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON * TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```

Then based what the application was doing with the database you would use the credentials that had sufficient access. I was recently looking into implementing this and was trying to see what the best practices for this are but I haven't been able to find anything.

Are there best practices for this? Is this something people actually do? Is it overkill with prepared and sanitized statements?

Comment: FYI: The usual permissions set is `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`.

Comment: I forgot about DELETE. I added it in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a best practice by itself.  Of course, having the right permissions is definitely a best practice.  And, having read-only access for read-only applications is good.

The simplest method for preventing injection is to use parameterized queries.  This is your first line of defense.  If all your queries are `select` queries, then connecting as a user with read-only access  is a win.

However, if you are modifying the database as well, this doesn't work.  Instead, wrap the code that makes the changes in stored procedures.  These can run under a different security context.  This allows the application to have read permissions and execute permissions, but not data modification permissions.

There are other advantages to using stored procedures instead of `insert`/`update`/`delete` statements directly.  For instance: you can log the operations, you can run additional logic, you can modify multiple tables at the same time, transactions can be hidden from the application.

Comment: I have seen parameterized queries as the way to go in a lot of places. I started wrapping my queries in stored procedures in pet projects a while ago just for portability. But I hadn't look into how the permissions differ between them and regular queries yet.